# Fluentd doesn't parse json log from docker

Tags: json, parsing, logging, fluentd, opensearch

I have some problems parsing json logs that were received from docker container. I know this question is probably a duplicate but none of the solutions found, including the documentation (https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/parser), helped.

Now my fluentd.conf like this:

```golang
  <source>
    @type forward
    port 24224
    bind "0.0.0.0"
  </source>

  <match mylog>
    @type opensearch
    @log_level "info"
    host "opensearch-node1"
    port 9200
    logstash_format true
    logstash_dateformat "%Y%m%d"
    logstash_prefix "mylog"
  </match>

  <filter **>
    @type parser
    key_name "log"
    hash_value_field "log"
    reserve_data true
    <parse>
      @type "json"
    </parse>
  </filter>
```

But it feels like the filter is not working because the log field does not change

Result in OpenSearch:

```json
{
  "_index": "mylog-20221024",
  "_id": "93cECoQBW3_q0OULbk2_",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "container_id": "47de762b4d113478ee125417abd9e6ec7d963aa0d77758fc92cf3a18b0d2ad86",
    "container_name": "/mylog",
    "source": "stdout",
    "log": "{\"time\":\"2022-10-24T15:42:48.480757224+03:00\",\"id\":\"\",\"remote_ip\":\"10.73.133.144\",\"host\":\"localhost:80\",\"method\":\"GET\",\"uri\":\"/metrics\"}",
    "@timestamp": "2022-10-24T12:42:48.000000000+00:00"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2022-10-24T12:42:48.000Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1666615368000
  ]
}
```

Expected:

```json
{
  "_index": "mylog-20221024",
  "_id": "93cECoQBW3_q0OULbk2_",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "container_id": "47de762b4d113478ee125417abd9e6ec7d963aa0d77758fc92cf3a18b0d2ad86",
    "container_name": "/mylog",
    "source": "stdout",
    "log": "{\"time\":\"2022-10-24T15:42:48.480757224+03:00\",\"id\":\"\",\"remote_ip\":\"10.73.133.144\",\"host\":\"localhost:80\",\"method\":\"GET\",\"uri\":\"/metrics\"}",
    "time": "2022-10-24T15:42:48.480757224+03:00",
    "id":"",
    "remote_ip":"10.73.133.144",
    "host":"localhost:80",
    "method":"GET",
    "uri":"/metrics",
    "@timestamp": "2022-10-24T12:42:48.000000000+00:00",
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2022-10-24T12:42:48.000Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1666615368000
  ]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: From your expected output, it looks like you're trying to enhance the log by adding more fields to it. You might want to look at https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/record_transformer or https://github.com/repeatedly/fluent-plugin-record-modifier.

Comment: Thanks! I try extract inner tags in json from "log". docs.fluentd.org/filter/record_transformer looks like what can help but I don't quite understand how to do what I need.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Yes, the [record_transformer](https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/record_transformer) should do what you want. Go through its documentation, examples, and other relevant SO Q&A. Hopefully, you'll get it to work as expected. Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like I can extract only previously known fields from json while I need to extract ALL fields from "log"

Comment: The value of `log` key is a string literal. You need to convert that to JSON and then you can access the nested fields and create new ones from them. Please take a look at the previous Q&A tagged `fluentd`. IIRC, there have been similar questions and you can leverage the answers and discussions from those threads.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem turned out to be very simple. The `<filter>` should be placed before the `<match>`. Now my `fluentd.conf` like this:

```golang
  <source>
    @type forward
    port 24224
    bind "0.0.0.0"
  </source>

  <filter mylog**>
    @type parser
    format json
    key_name log
    reserve_data true
    reserve_time true
    inject_key_prefix logs.
  </filter>

  <match mylog>
    @type opensearch
    @log_level "info"
    host "opensearch-node1"
    port 9200
    logstash_format true
    logstash_dateformat "%Y%m%d"
    logstash_prefix "mylog"
  </match>
```